# TS + React: Conditionally use interface based on props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a component that either should receive a prop called `text` or children - not both nor neither.

**✓ Allow**

```
<NotificationBar text="Demo"/>
<NotificationBar>Demo</NotificationBar>
```

**✗ Disallow**

```
<NotificationBar/>
<NotificationBar text="Demo">Demo</NotificationBar>
```

---

**Source**

```
interface IWithChildren {
    children: ReactNode;
    text?: never;
}

interface IWithText {
    text: JSX.Element | string;
    children?: never;
}

type TNotification = (IWithChildren | IWithText);

export const NotificationBar = ({ text, children }: TNotification) => {}
```

TypeScript-wise it works, but React gives a warning when using `text` prop only:

```
<NotificationBar text="Demo"/>
```

> Element NotificationBar doesn't have required attribute children

Other than that, it works as expected.

How else can I make an interface to my React component, that matches an interface based on the props given, and not get a warning?

Comment: Can you maybe reproduce this here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts ?

Comment: The warning you get is given by your IDE? Because I just try to copy/paste what you written, and no warning is given by VSCode

Comment: I understand your thinking, but maybe you should consider sticking with the children prop only. This API design is a bit confusing imo. I think it's a global standart to use children prop for such cases, not coming from the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `never` on the interface keys that are conditional.

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-almeida-o4wxj

Comment: this link died :(